# How To Set iptables log rules for PSAD with UFW?

Tags: security, iptables, ufw, psad

For PSAD to work, I need to add the following iptables rules and enable packet logging :

```
iptables -A INPUT -j LOG
iptables -A FORWARD -j LOG
ip6tables -A INPUT -j LOG
ip6tables -A FORWARD -j LOG
```

I use UFW on my system. So, how can I add these rules with UFW?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just [enable logging](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UFW#Logging).

```
sudo ufw logging on
```

Comment: I did that, but when reloading psad, it sends an email to me giving this error : [-] You may just need to add a default logging rule to the /sbin/iptables
    'filter' 'INPUT' chain on sinha.  For more information,
    see the file "FW_HELP" in the psad sources directory or visit:

    http://www.cipherdyne.org/psad/docs/fwconfig.html

[-] You may just need to add a default logging rule to the /sbin/ip6tables
    'filter' 'INPUT' chain on sinha.  For more information,
    see the file "FW_HELP" in the psad sources directory or visit:

    http://www.cipherdyne.org/psad/docs/fwconfig.html

Answer (score 5):

As the poster above says, you will need to enable logging with the command

```
 sudo ufw logging on
```

But I found that I still needed to add the iptables rules. To do this run each of the commands below (note that you must have `sudo` in front)

```
 sudo iptables -A INPUT -j LOG
 sudo iptables -A FORWARD -j LOG
 sudo ip6tables -A INPUT -j LOG
 sudo ip6tables -A FORWARD -j LOG
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to add extra rules to ufw to satisfy psad. Edit following two files:

```
sudo vi /etc/ufw/before.rules

sudo vi /etc/ufw/before6.rules
```

To both files listed above, **add following lines** for psad, at the very end, but **before** `COMMIT`

```
# custom logging directives for psad
-A INPUT -j LOG
-A FORWARD -j LOG

# don't delete the 'COMMIT' line or these rules won't be processed
COMMIT
```

Next restart ufw

```
sudo ufw disable
sudo ufw enable
```

and then check if it worked with

```
sudo psad --fw-analyze

[+] Parsing /sbin/iptables INPUT chain rules.
[+] Parsing /sbin/ip6tables INPUT chain rules.
[+] Firewall config looks good.
[+] Completed check of firewall ruleset.
[+] Results in /var/log/psad/fw_check
[+] Exiting.
```

That's it. Read more tips and tricks on [how to configure PSAD with UFW](https://gist.github.com/netson/c45b2dc4e835761fbccc)

Answer (score 0):

Like darronz mentioned you still have to add iptable rules. As you are using ufw the easiest way to create persistent rules would be to edit `/etc/ufw/before.rules` and `/etc/ufw/before6.rules` and add the following lines

```
-A INPUT -j LOG
-A FORWARD -j LOG
```

at the end, but before the `COMMIT`.